# Why are my files being multiplied ???? renameTo();

Tags: java, android, file-rename

I have an issue with renaming a file it seems every time I try to they end up being multiplied and are created 2 times the amount I.e. if I have one song that I want to rename in the list view and hold the on long click event it doubles the amount say 2 to 4 songs and 4 to 12 and so on in my list view . I'm using an OnItemLongClickListener to handle the files being created for each item click on the list view to be renamed . I have no idea why it isn't working  ... I have even tried setting the position to

```
    String pos = lv.getItemAtPosition(position);
```

And many other ways ...
But no use it ends up being a random number that is being multiplied ... My question is why ; how can fix .

```
    downloadsList.setOnItemLongClickListener(
        new OnItemLongClickListener(){
            @Override
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent , View view , int position , long itemId ){
                EditText bar = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.search);
                String to = bar.getText().toString();
(ListView) findViewById(R.id.downloads);
                File[] pos = files.listFiles();
                File filein = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS).toString() , files.getName());
                File fileTo = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS).toString() + "/" + to);
                if(!filein.exists()){
                    filein.renameTo(fileTo);
                } else {
                    try {
                        throw new IOException("File exists");
                    }catch (IOException e){
                           e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

                finish();
                overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
                startActivity(getIntent());
                overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
                return true;
            }
        });
```

Here is the list view method to populate it

```
    private void ShowLists(){
    files = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory( Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS).toString());

    downloads = files.listFiles(new FileFilter(){
        @Override
        public boolean accept(File file){
            String ext = file.getName();
            if(ext.endsWith(".mp3")){
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
    mp3s = new String[downloads.length];
        for(int i = 0 ; i < mp3s.length; i++){
            mp3s[i] = downloads[i].getName();       
        }
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.downloads, R.id.textviewone , mp3s);
    ListView downloadsList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.downloads);
    downloadsList.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

This is before https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vv107.jpg

This is after I click the long click to rename a file and the on going complication https://i.stack.imgur.com/eWxcR.jpg

**UPDATED CODE**

```
    public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent , View view , int position , long itemId ){
                EditText bar = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.search);
                String to = bar.getText().toString();
                ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.downloads);
                String pos = lv.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
                File filein = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS).toString() , pos);
                File fileTo = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS).toString() , to);
                filein.renameTo(fileTo);
                finish();
                overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
                startActivity(getIntent());
                overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
                return true;
            }
        });
```

Comment: Could you be more specific on "they end being multiplied on my List View"?

Comment: How are you building the List View? I guess is on the onStart()

Comment: I have a method named ShowLists I think its called and I'm using an ArrayAdapter to populate the list view I can post it

Comment: Have you checked the folder, if the more files are indeed created?

Comment: Yes they are being created in the android folder and also the app

Comment: Also the app meaning in the list view

Comment: I have posted up two photos to show what I mean

Comment: What are you doing in onItemLongClick? Your code does not make sense. You are not using `int position` at all. So which file would you rename? A random one. Very strange that you try to list files there too.

Comment: `pos = files.listFiles();` Why this statement? You are not using `pos`. And we can conclude that `files` is a directory. `.... ).toString() , files.getName())`. And here you consider 'files' to be the file that you are going to rename.

Comment: I tried using lv.getItemAtPosition(position); but it works but keeps on "multiplying" the files into doubles . and how would I make this work ? I want to rename the file that is clicked on . if a list view item containing the file I'm guessing at that position will be long clicked then it takes the EditText and renames it to whatever that may be.

Comment: I have tried many codes and many different ways maybe the norm you would say but either way ... They double . how can I fix it to not double ?

Comment: I want "to" to be the file to be renamed the EditText whatever the user types in then long clicks the event will change the name of the file

Comment: Well first post code where you do all things right. It iss prettybad also that you have to determine the source directory of your source file.

Comment: `want "to" to be the file to be renamed ` ??? What do you mean? You are renaming `filein` to `fileTo`. Nothing else.

Comment: `String pos`. What do you get in pos? Toast it to see. Why finish() and startActivity? All makes no sense. You still use Envirinment.    ? Why you know the source dir. Dont determine again!

Comment: The toast showed the name of the file

Comment: Then rename `pos` to `fileName`. File filein = new File(files, fileName); And now you do a better `fileTo`.

Comment: Its still giving me the same result

Comment: Remove all the code after .renameTo().  And just restart your app to see.

Comment: Do away with that edit text and just use File fileTo = new File(files,fileName+".xxx"); and report what the new name becomes.

Comment: If you restart again, is the old file still there? You are unclear about what happens. What is the new name? Please just add an extra extension as i suggested. Makes it much easier to see what you do and happens.

Comment: That didn't work either it just double still